# spring portal gatting the response as a json

Tags: spring, websphere-portal

please find the bellow code

Bring resource JSP

```
function makeAJAXCall() {
    dojo.byId("containerDiv").innerHTML = "Request in progress...";
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url : "<portlet:resourceURL id="sampleAJAX"/>",
```

This is correct code in spring portal for getting the response as a json

Comment: I am not able to understand your question, what you are trying to do and what is the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

is not specific to spring it is portal, and your portlet have to override serveResource or if you are using spring controller use @ResourceMapping

whatever the way you are using you have to generate the json response using one of json frameworks like jackson or gson and sent the json in response stream